# Adding existing cell values with a script in google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet in Google Docs where i could track my data. I already have some starting values entered into cells, also some cells with functions. I wanted to make a script that would add these values in a list where are previous records.

To explain it more clearly.

I have a table with values:

[A1]    [B1]    [C1]     [D1]           etc.

[24.52] [12.84] [=A1-B1] [=(100/A1)*B1] etc.

After I press a button I want these values to be added in a list in another sheet (preferred) or in the same sheet just under everything I already have. These values in list shouldn't change anymore after I edit my main table.

List should be like this:

[.....] [.....] [.....] [......] <--- [...] that's where previous values were added

[24.52] [12.84] [11.68] [52.36%] <--- last added values

New data would be added in a new row.

I have a script but there is a problem with adding values to the cells. When I press that button it adds #NAME? in cells with comment "unknown range name A16" not their real values.

I use this script - This one only add new values to the same sheet:

`function AddRecord() {`

```
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = doc.getLastRow();
  var cell = doc.getRange('A1').offset(lastRow, 0);
  cell.setValue('=A16');
  cell.offset(0, 1).setValue('=B16');
  cell.offset(0, 2).setValue('=C16');
  cell.offset(0, 3).setValue('=D16');
}
```

=A16, =B16, =C16, =D16 are cells that contain those values i need but how should i write this code that it would add them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if I completely understood your question. 
To copy the values of the last row from "Tabellenblatt1" to a new row in "Tabellenblatt2", you could use the following simple function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetFrom = doc.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  var sheetTo = doc.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt2");  
  var lastRow = sheetFrom.getLastRow();
  var cell = sheetFrom.getRange('A1').offset(lastRow, 0);
  var rowTo = sheetTo.getLastRow() + 1;
  for( var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
     sheetTo.getRange(rowTo, i).setValue( sheetFrom.getRange(lastRow, i).getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, that actually works even better as long as I put all my necessary values in last row. Thanks a lot :)